# Generating QR Code with SwiftUI shows empty picture

Tags: qr-code, swiftui, cifilter

im trying to generate a QR code in my app. The problem is that whenever I do the picture is just an empty square. I stripped down the code to the basics to try and show my problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "circle.fill")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(Color.green)

        }.onAppear {
            let myString = "Hello There"
            let data = myString.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
            guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return }
            qrFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            guard let qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return }
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
            let scaledQrImage = qrImage.transformed(by: transform)
            self.image = Image(uiImage: UIImage(ciImage: scaledQrImage))
        }
    }
}
```

The Result is this: 
[image: Screenshot of Result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI: UIImage (QRCode) does not load after calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172122/swiftui-uiimage-qrcode-does-not-load-after-calling-function)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your `CIImage` is not actually "produced". You see, a `CIImage` is just a *recipe* for an image that needs to be rendered by a `CIContext` into an actual bitmap image.

The (poorly documented) convenient initializer `UIImage(ciImage:)` only works if the destination you assign the image to understands that the pixels of the `UIImage` are not yet *there* and need to be rendered first. `UIImageView` could handle this, but it seems SwiftUI's `Image` doesn't.

What you need to do is to create a `CIContext` (once, maybe as a property of your view) and use it to render your barcode image into a bitmap like this:

```
let cgImage = self.ciContext.createCGImage(scaledQrImage, from: scaledQrImage.extent)
self.image = Image(uiImage: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage))
```

Comment: You are blazing a trail for us all! Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
func returnQRData(str: String) -> Data {
     let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
     let data = str.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
     filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
     let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)


     let image = filter?.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform)
     let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: image!)

     return uiImage.pngData()!
}

Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.returnQRData(str: "www.apple.com")) ?? UIImage(named: "noImage1")!)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .padding()
```

Comment: This is quite inefficient as `returnQRData` needlessly encodes the image as a PNG data stream only for it to be immediately decoded again. Using a CIContext to render to a CGImage will achieve the same thing without encoding to PNG