# UIView.transition animation It only works once, a second time the picture just disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

How to make the animation consistent?

```
func addBlurTo(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    guard let ciImg = CIImage(image: image) else { return nil }
    let blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    blur?.setValue(ciImg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    blur?.setValue(1 , forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    if let outputImg = blur?.outputImage {
        return UIImage(ciImage: outputImg)
    }
    return nil
}
```

And for Button:

```
@IBAction func Button7(_ sender: UIButton) {

        UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            guard let testImage = self.imageView.image else {return}
            self.imageView.image = self.addBlurTo(testImage)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: @ jawadAli. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your function a bit to the following and it should work. The problem is the conversion from a ciImage to a UIImage without using context. See here:

[If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the value of the property is NULL.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624147-cgimage)

and here:

[Generating qr code with swiftui shows empty picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239980/generating-qr-code-with-swiftui-shows-empty-picture)

```
func addBlurTo(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

            guard let ciImg = CIImage(image: image) else { return nil }
            let blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
            blur?.setValue(ciImg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            blur?.setValue(1 , forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
            if let outputImg = blur?.outputImage {
                let context = CIContext()
                guard let cgOutput = context.createCGImage(outputImg, from: outputImg.extent) else { return nil }
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgOutput)
            }
            return nil
        }
```